# How to import CSV containing double quotes in non-quoted-field into mongoDB using mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb, csv, escaping, double-quotes, mongoimport

I am trying to import the CSV data below into a mongo DB using mongoimport.

`B,P-212384,4,0085,text "string" with double-quotes,SI-581G`

I get the following error:

`Failed: read error on entry #1: line 1, column 23: bare " in non-quoted-field`

Even double quoting (`""`) doesn't work as that only applies to CSV fields that are double-quoted (e.g. `"text ""string"" with double-quotes"`).  And backslashes are not a valid escape character according to the docs.

So my question is does anyone know how to massage my CSV data so that mongoimport won't complain?

**UPDATE - 02/28/2016**

[CSV Reader on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/master/mongoimport/csv/reader.go)

If you search for `LazyQuotes` in that file you will see that is exactly what I need.

`If LazyQuotes is true, a quote may appear in an unquoted field and a non-doubled quote may appear in a quoted field.`

But it doesn't appear I can use `LazyQuotes` from the command line.  Any thoughts or insight?

Comment: See if this works
`B,P-212384,4,85,"text ""string"" with double-quotes",SI-581G`

Comment: Yes that definitely works, I tried that prior to posting my question.  That solution requires me to massage the entire CSV file which contains 735K entries.  Not a deal breaker if push comes to shove but figured I would post a question before going down that path.  I am updating my question with additional information, let me know if you have any input on this.

Comment: I simply pasted your csv data in a notepad file, saved it with a `.csv` extension and opened it in MS Excel. It reformatted the whole file correctly. Then I opened the csv file again, this time in Notepad, copied the contents and pasted it here. Simple isn't it. Same can be done with 735k entries.

Comment: I don't know if my version of Excel is too old but I had previously tried to open the file and it will only import 65536 entries.  So that isn't going to work for me.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Your suggestion worked for me. I'm using excel 2012.